# How to get the class name that fired an Activity?

Tags: android, android-intent

A subclass of AccountAuthenticatorActivity, is fired, can call the getIntent() method, but How can I know the exact class or Activity that fired up this Activity?.

It has no Intent Filters on AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: why do you want to know the class that started the activity? What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Perhaps you could pass in an extra and use that to determine who started you.

Comment: @FoamyGuy Because I want to understand better how authentication/AccountManager works in Android. Cannot pass an extra since the activity was not fired from my project source directly.